# What is the Hardness and Hitpoints of Mage Armor?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic

In a 3.5 game I play, our DM has a rule for armor that it wears out and breaks over time through natural wear and tear unless we maintain it. He uses a table much like

http://www.d20srd.org/srd/exploration.htm#tableSubstanceHardnessAndHitPoints

to determine how strong some things are (so armor would have 30 hitpoints and a hardness of 10), but I see no entry for the kind of armor generated from the spell Mage Armor (http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/mageArmor.htm) nor "force" objects in general. What is the actual hardness and hitpoints of something like that, or is it even possible to calculate that?

Comment: Discussion should be in [chat]. Comments are for clarification only. With that said and reviewing the deleted comments, I do believe that you would benefit, twiggy, from discussing your more abstract concerns that do not yet merit questions in chat.

Comment: You do realize that Mage Armor only lasts 1 hour per caster level (to start with), and therefore already "wears and tears" with a well-defined mechanic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a field of magical force: it cannot be broken and doesn't suffer wear-and-tear, so there is no reason for it to have hardness or hit points.